# Objective-C NSRunLoop & NotificationCenterDelegate not functional when spawned on Rust worker thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, rust, interop, unusernotification

I'm currently trying to use Rust C interop in order to send actional desktop notifications (using a modified version of [this](https://github.com/h4llow3En/mac-notification-sys) lib). The main goal here would be to handle these notification sending events on separate threads like so:

```rust
thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
  sys::sendNotification(
    NSString::from_str(&title).deref(),
    NSString::from_str(&message).deref(),
    NSString::from_str(&uri).deref(),
    NSString::from_str(&img.unwrap_or_default()).deref(),
  );
});
```

This would allow me to have multiple notification 'handlers' running at the same time (vs. just being able to have a single notification displayed at once), and would also allow my main process to run without being blocked. Given the nature of the program (web-scraper), I don't want scraping halted whenever a notification is being displayed.

That said, this approach is somewhat problematic because the [underlying obj-c code](https://github.com/h4llow3En/mac-notification-sys/blob/master/objc/notify.m#L35) relies on NSRunLoop to handle click events (e.g., user clicks on the action to open a web page) through the created [NotificationCenterDelegate](https://github.com/h4llow3En/mac-notification-sys/blob/master/objc/notify.h#L34) instance. Per my knowledge (feel free to fact-check me on this I'm not familiar with obj-c), NSRunLoops only operate on the main thread and this code is rendered useless if ran on a worker... The notification still sends in this scenario, but events aren't processed.

Is there a way to handle this that is more effective than running my scraping logic on a separate loop and sending notif-send events to the main thread for processing (which will probably be halted by a notification that I hadn't opened)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is (or can be) one `NSRunLoop` per thread, not only the main thread. But it's still the case that GUI stuff generally needs to run on the main thread.

I recommend that you take the approach of running scraping on a separate thread. This is generally a good idea for *any* combination of long-running work and GUI — it ensures that the work cannot cause the UI to hang or hiccup.